# Two players A and B throw a pair of dice

Tags: conditional-probability

If two players A and B throw a pair of dice. A will win if he gets a sum of 7 and B will win if he gets a sum of 5. If A starts the game what is the probability that 3 will appear on one of the die in the last throw

Comment: Hi! What have you already done to solve this problem? If you tell us what exactly you don't understand about the problem, we can help you then.

Comment: I am getting confused how to consider the conditional probability in this case

Comment: Do A and B each throw once, or do they alternate until one wins?

Comment: @JRAVINDRANATH    Conflict here.  On the one hand you haven't shown **any work**.  On the other hand, cond. probability problems are tricky.  I will give subsequent comment that provides outline of solution.  Ask that you try for 24 hours and then if needed, show your work, editing your question.

Comment: @JRAVINDRANATH  You need to calculate 4 variables: a = chance that 1st player wins, b = chance that 2nd player wins [which is = to (1-a)], c = chance that 3 appears on last throw if 1st player wins, d = chance that 3 appears on last throw if 2nd player wins.  Then, answer is ac + bd.

Comment: P(A)=12/17, P(B) = 5/17, P(C) and P(D) I am unable to get it

Comment: @JRAVINDRANATH assume the last throw is a 7.  how many different ways can 7 appear as the sum of the two dice? how many of those ways involve a 3 appearing on one of the two dice?

Comment: P(C)=2/6 and P(D)=2/4

Comment: If it is ac+bd = 4/17+5/34 = 13/34 but the answer given is 11/28